# Instantiating Safe Accounts from Solidity Contracts

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, account-abstraction

Is it feasible to create Safe accounts directly from a Solidity contract, conduct setups like registering modules and safeguards, and then pass control to an EOA? I'm aware of the Typescript SDK, but I'm keen on a contract-centric method. I've begun diving into [SafeProxyFactory.sol](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/proxies/SafeProxyFactory.sol). Could you provide any documentation or guidance on this?

Thank you in advance!